# Profiling python to a fixed call depth

Tags: python, profiling

The output of standard profilers is typically clogged up with details on time spent by low-level functions.  In a large, complex project, I want to first get a general idea for which parts of my code are taking longer than others.

Specifically, I wonder if there is a way to tell the profiler to report results limited to a specific call depth. For example, setting depth = 0 should show only the total time for an entire python script; depth = 1 could show time for individual lines on the script; depth = 2 could show time for functions called by functions in the script, and so on.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2):

It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but I personally find [pyprof2calltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2calltree/) very useful. It converts the output of the built-in cProfile to a format that is understtod by tools like [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).
(there are also implementations using a different widget set, e.g. qcachegrind).

Tools like KCacheGrind, among other things, allow you to visualize the call tree of the profiled code, and it's easy too see which callees of a particular calling function (i.e. a top-level main function) consume the most time - check the attached screenshot for a better idea. [image: profile visualization]
(Image source: [link](http://blog.equanimity.nl/blog/2013/04/24/fprof-kcachegrind/))

With `pyprof2calltree` and `KCacheGrind` installed, visualizing a profiler output is just a matter of a single command:

```
pyprof2calltree -k -i todo_profile.cprof
```

The `-i` option specifies what the **i**nput file is, and the `-k` switch runs the installed visualizer tool (e.g. KCacheGrind).

Comment: Hello plamut, could you tell me how i create the todo_profile.cprof file?

Comment: @Ragon It's the output of the built-in profile. When done with profiling, you can use its `dump_stats()` method ([official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#profile.Profile.dump_stats)) to store the stats in a file, which can be then visualized with KCacheGrind or any other compatible visualization tool.